# Create a fixed scrollable sidebar in bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position, sidebar

How to create a fixed sidebar scrollable till the footer comes and siblings div content comes to an end.
I made a sidebar containing some info and next to it dynamic news posts appear. I want to make sidebar fixed and scrollable relative to posts section.
Structure od code is something like this
1.. bootstrap container
2.. Row
3.. col-4
4..side bar here..
5..col-8
6..news posts content here
page contains header and footer as well.

```html
<?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters" id="pics">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="pic-img"><img src="images/article-img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="pic-img"><img src="images/article-img2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="pic-img"><img src="images/article-img3.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Articles</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="row" id="sub-content">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div id="search-box">
                <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search blog">
                <a type="button" id="search-btn">Search</a>
                </div>
                <ul id="categories">
                    <li>Categories</li>
                    <li><a type="button">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a type="button">Life Style</a></li>
                    <li><a type="button">Health</a></li>
                    <li><a type="button">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li><a type="button">Fashion</a></li>
                    <li><a type="button">Travel</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="latest-feeds">
                    <p id="feed-heading">Latest Feeds</p>
                    <div class="feed-content">
                        <img src="images/temp3.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="feed-info">
                            <p class="feed-title">This post is about this title get to know</p>
                            <p class="feed-date">20 September 2021</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feed-content">
                        <img src="images/temp2.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="feed-info">
                            <p class="feed-title">This post is about this title get to know</p>
                            <p class="feed-date">20 September 2021</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feed-content">
                        <img src="images/temp5.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="feed-info">
                            <p class="feed-title">This post is about this title get to know</p>
                            <p class="feed-date">20 September 2021</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feed-content">
                        <img src="images/temp4.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="feed-info">
                            <p class="feed-title">This post is about this title get to know</p>
                            <p class="feed-date">20 September 2021</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul id="footer-tags">
                        <li>Tags</li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Home</span>
                            <span>Blog</span>
                            <span>Post</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Fashion</span>
                            <span>Health</span>
                            <span>Environment</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Life</span>
                            <span>Travel</span>
                            <span>About</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Sports</span>
                            <span>Nature</span>
                            <span>Blogger</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Category</span>
                            <span>Art</span>
                            <span>Fine</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
                <div class="row" id="articles">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp4.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp2.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp3.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp5.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp4.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp2.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <a href="#" class="post-img">
                                <img src="images/temp3.jpg" alt="Image">
                            </a>
                            <div class="post-info-container">
                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <span class="post-category"><a href="#">Category</a></span>
                                    <span class="post-date">20 october 2019</span>
                                    <span class="post-author"><a href="#">By Author</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <h4 class="post-title">This Post is about this</h4>
                                <p class="post-description">Blogging refers to writing, photography, and other media that's self-published online. Blogging started as an opportunity for individuals to write diary-style entries</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
<style>
    .post-content  img{
        height: 320px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the scrollspy, somthing like [THIS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/scrollspy/) maybe?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).